# How to pipe a file upload without dependencies like Multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data, body-parser

I'm using express and I would like to pipe a POST request coming from the client directly to a writeable stream to Google Storage, in order to upload the file without storing it in memory or on the disk first. I did some research and found various examples, which seem to work. However, all the solutions I found use dependencies like multer or busyboy. For learning purposes and to avoid unecessary overheat, I'm interested in how to achieve the desired solution without these kind of dependencies. I've been searching for a while but unfortunately couldn't find any examples. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just go read the source code of the proven modules.  The reason for the modules is that there are a lot of http and mime standards to handle how the incoming data can be tagged/encoded/formatted which, believe me, is a lot more tedious detail than most of us ever want to get involved with (if we can avoid it).  Using one of the pre-built modules will avoid an enormous amount of tedium.  These modules are designed to be efficient.  If you want to stream the incoming data to another source, you should be able to do that. You don't need to code it yourself to be efficient.

Comment: FYI, here's the [source for multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and the [source for busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy).  Note, multer uses busboy.